# How to validate special character entry in any controls within a page?

Tags: asp.net

I have designed  a page where user can write messages and send within a group but i want that if they enter any special character like <>?#@ etc a msg should be displayed irrespective of the crashing of the page.

Can anyone help me out???

Comment: Be careful with this. You need to sanitize all input and limit the special characters that can be entered. Have you tried using an editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that you have to use javaScript validation or any server site validation
for javaScript

function validate(inputText)
{
if(inputText.match(/[<>]/))
return false;
}
function TextBoxValidate()
{
var txt1=document.getElementById(TextBoxId).value;
if(!(validate(inputText)))
{
alert("incorrect text")
return false;
}
else
return true;
}

call these function in that text box where you want to validate by using onClientClick="return TextBoxValidate();"

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 possibilities for doing that.

A) You are adding a regularexpression validator to each control
B) You use a customvalidator which you can bind to each control too

First solution is the better one for you.

How you do it? See here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/aspnetvalidation.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's not reccommended but you can use ValidateRequest="false" in the page declaration to allow values like that to be sucessfully posted back.

e.g. `<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" ValidateRequest="false"..`